# How to paint vertical lines between rows in DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, .net-4.5, paint

I need to paint some sort of brackets between rows in order to let the user know that rows have some relation (I don't want to merge cells). So far looks nice but when scrolling becomes a mess.

[image: When loading]
[image: When scrolling down and up]

I haven't been able to figure it out. Isn't there a way to draw persistent vertical lines to keep them in order?

```
Private Sub dgcontrol_CellPainting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles dgcontrol.CellPainting
If sender.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "xrow2" Then
 Dim rec1 As Rectangle = dgcontrol.GetCellDisplayRectangle(2, 0, False)
 Dim rec2 As Rectangle = dgcontrol.GetCellDisplayRectangle(2, 1, False)
 Dim gridBrush As Brush = New SolidBrush(Color.Red)
 Dim gridLinePen As Pen = New Pen(gridBrush, 2)
 e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, New Point(rec1.X + rec1.Width - 2 - rec1.Width / 5, rec1.Y + rec1.Height / 3), New Point(rec1.X + rec1.Width - 2, rec1.Y + rec1.Height / 3))
 e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, New Point(rec2.X + rec1.Width - 2 - rec1.Width / 5, rec2.Y + rec2.Height - rec2.Height / 3), New Point(rec2.X + rec1.Width - 2, rec2.Y + rec2.Height - rec2.Height / 3))
 e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, New Point(rec1.X + rec1.Width - 3, rec1.Y + rec1.Height / 3), New Point(rec2.X + rec1.Width - 3, rec2.Y + rec2.Height - rec2.Height / 3))
 e.Handled = False
End If End Sub
```

Comment: Painting lines in the datagridview is a mess because you always have to recalculate. A small suggestion is to use colors in the cels to indicate the relation.

Comment: Well, I had to add a thin column and paint png's as well as the whole cell, that solved my problem, I couldn't find a real solution.